# How fast to become "most wanted" in medieval world?

Tags: internal-consistency, medieval, communication

This is the question every RPG player or D&D player had in mind: "What happens if I kill them all?" So, lets ask the question:

Imagine typical medieval fantasy kingdom. There is some magic and different races, namely Dwarves and Elves.

To this kingdom enters group of highly trained people. They enter via the mountains and start their journey in small village just on the outskirts of this kingdom.

This group of people has a fight in local pub, resulting by killing all the villagers. (Say 50 -ish people killed in total).

Only one villager survived and did run to nearest small city to say the news. Our group of heroes in the meantime left in different path, with intent not to continue to kill, lay low and maybe seek for another heroic opportunities.

**How much time is needed to make them kingdom's most wanted?**

Things to consider:

- Villager to survive has seen all the slaughter happening in said village
- This villager can also describe the group.
- The group of heroes sticks together and also starts by wearing recognizable outfits (namely, just having an armor is thing to give you off)
- The group spent no time trying to hide their crime
- Fastest way to communicate in this kingdom are mail pidgeons
- We are in huge kingdom, say [as big as Poland during Jagelonian rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Poland_during_the_Jagiellonian_dynasty)

Comment: What do you think that "most wanted" means in a medieval kingdom? In a real medieval kingdom (conveniently placed in the High Middle Ages, say around 1200 CE), what would happen is that the group would be declared outlaws, which in practice meant than anybody would be welcome to try and kill them. There was no police, there was no central law enforcing organization. In the Middle Ages, if someone was murdered, the expectation was that the relatives of the victim would apprehend the killer and present them to be tried. The monarch would certainly not spend a dime chasing random killers.

Comment: Definitely related, possible duplicate: [How quickly and accurately should news travel in a rural medieval setting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/13/29)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That answers my question! Thanks for helping with this. :) Marking as a duplicate. Ok, edit. Can you please mark it as a duplicate? :)

Comment: Someone beat me to it.